# LibGdx set background image (responsive)

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm new in LibGDx, I'm trying to set a background image that adjust to the screen without resizing. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To draw your image on your whole screen use

```
batch.draw(texture,0,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```

But it depends of more things, such as are you using any viewports, cameras, etc..

You could show us your code first.